# "Figures/Numbers" (plural) vs "Figure/Number" (singular) for describing a single piece of data in graphs

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I want to describe the following graphs (for IELTS exam).

For example for the first graph, if we want to talk about multiple figures we can definitely use plural form (numbers/figures) and say

> 1 Generally, the **numbers/figures** for part-time education are more than full-time education.

But what about a piece of data in the graph? For, example can we say:

> 2 The **numbers/figures** for males engaged in part-time education in 1970/71 are 1000.

Or for the second graph:

> 3 The **numbers/figures** for Italy in 1967 are about 4 metric tonnes.

I have seen that people use plural form of "numbers/figures" for referring to a single piece of data (a single number). But is it correct? Isn't it better to use a singular form ("number/figure")? What is the wisdom behind using a plural form for referring to a single piece of data?

[image: graph one]

[image: graph two]

An example of using a plural noun (figures or numbers) to refer to a single bar in the graph that only a single number is associated with:

Page 145 (the section: test practice, Model answer) of [this official Cambridge book (vocabulary for IELTS)](http://ngoaingu.vimaru.edu.vn/wp-content/uploads/documents/Vocabulary-for-IELTS.pdf). It says: "In the 1960s, the figures for the wealthy countries ...":
[image]
, whereas it refers to a single bar in the graph on page 71 of this book:

[image]

I think plurality of "figures" has nothing to do with the plurality of "countries" since "wealthy countries" is just a category of data and only a single bar is allocated to "wealthy countries" in 1960s. Moreover, in the next sentence, it has referred to it by "This figure"!!! Overall, is it a good style of writing? Why has it said "the figures" and then said "This figure" and has not used a single form (only plural or only singular)?

Comment: One bar on a graph still represents a plural term. Single piece of data??

Comment: @Lambie Is it just a rule in English grammar that I should just obey without questioning? In my mother language we use singular form for this and it have made some confusion for me. (what is wrong with the phrase "a single piece of data"??)

Comment: Single piece of data is not wrong linguistically. I just cannot figure out what you are using it for. As I said, any of those bars contain many people. BUT: each bar has only **one number or figure associated with it**. SO: The number or figure for Italy in 1967 is about 4 metric tonnes. Each bar or point on the x-y axis line represents a single number or figure.

Comment: But look at page 145 (the section: test practice, Model answer) of this official Cambridge book (vocabulary for IELTS)  [ http://ngoaingu.vimaru.edu.vn/wp-content/uploads/documents/Vocabulary-for-IELTS.pdf ]. It says: "In the 1960s, the figures for the wealthy countries ...", whereas it refers to a single bar in the graph on page 71 of this book.

Comment: Boy, that took forever to load. Although not shown, those are the **figures** for wealthy countr**ries** for that decade. That's why figures is plural. One bar represents many countries. This would not even require a chart to say why the word figures is plural....

Comment: No, I know this is for wealthy countries but a single number and a single bar is used to describe all of them. There are not multiple numbers for a number of different wealthy countries. Here, "wealthy countries" is more of a category for sorting data. It is a number for a bunch of wealthy countries collectively. You can search "Cambridge vocabulary for IELTS" and I am sure there are a lot of other links that work better. However I provided figures for this example in the question.

Comment: The single bar represents wealthy countries. **They say figures due to countries being plural despite their only being one bar** for the 1960's! See? :)

Comment: I updated the image that I uploaded in the question and added the subsequent sentence of it. It has said: "This figure is ...". So why in the next sentence it has referred to it in a singular form?

Comment: And also it has said "**that** of the non-global countries" NOT "**those** of the non-global countries". Why when it comes to wealthy countries at the first place has it used plural form and then it has followed with singular form for non-global countries?

Comment: *because* it says: This figure [**referring to wealthy countries all together**] is double that for non-global countries. So, in fact the writers use both singular and plural.